# Как сделать регистрацию в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите как сделать регистрацию в Wordpress, стоит задача в простой регистрации, e-mail и имя, но личного кабинета нет, никакой административной части для пользователя, регистрация нужна для того чтобы пользователь мог видеть скрытую рубрику, как это сделать? 
Т.е. если пользователь произвел регистрацию и вошел, тогда он видит дополнительную рубрику в меню.

```
<form>
     <input class="form__input form__input_popup icon-1" name='' type="text" placeholder="E-mail" />
     <input class="form__input form__input_popup icon-2" name='' type="text" placeholder="******" />
     <input class="button button_popup" type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Регистрация:
Вставляем в functions.php

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_'user_registration', 'user_registration` ); 
add_action( 'admin_post_'user_registration', 'user_registration` );

function user_registration() { 
            // $user_name и user_email берем из формы регистрации
            // Таже настоятельно рекомендую провалидировать данные из формы и использовать wp_nonce_field();
            $random_password = wp_generate_password(15, false);
            $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $random_password, $user_email );
            if(is_wp_error( $user_id )){
                // Обрабатываем ошибку если пользователь не создался
                $user_id->get_error_message();
            }else{
                // Устанавоиваем роль пользователю, для данного случая так как для юзера не должна быть видима админка я бы рекомендовал создать кастомную роль, а потом по ней срыть и закрыть от него все что не не стоит видеть
                $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
                $user->set_role( 'contributor' );
                // отправляем пользователю письмо с его паролем
                wp_mail( $user_email, 'Welcome!', 'Your Password: ' . $random_password );
            }
        }
```

2) Акшен формы заменяем на

```
<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>
```

3) В форму вставляем скрытое поле:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="user_registration">
```

4) Отображение скрытой категории:

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
    // можем выводить срытую категрию
}
```

Comment: Подскажите куда этот код? в шаблон регистрации?

Comment: я выше закинул поля, подскажите куда значения подставлять что-бы забирать данные

Comment: Точнее как это все обработать, в тег form метод какой-то и экшн?

Comment: Модифицировал ответ

Answer (score 0):

При выводе меню нужно проверять, что возвращает функция

```
is_user_logged_in();
```

и если она вернула true, значит, пользователь зарегистрирован на сайте и вошел под своим именем и паролем.

В этом случае ему нужно показать требуемую рубрику в меню, в противном случае - не выводить ее на экран.